Is it possible to construct a regular directed graph with 9 vertices, 36 directed edges, and no cycles of length 3 or lower?
(I'm somewhat new to graph theory so I apologize if I get some terminology wrong)
Is it possible to make a directed graph satisfying the following properties?:

The graph has 9 vertices.
The graph is regular; Each vertex has 4 direct successors and 4 direct predecessors, for a total of 36 directed edges.
There are no cycles of length 1 or 3, meaning vertices don't point at themselves, and there are no triangular cycles. Optionally, 2-cycles can also disallowed.
Being connected is not required.

How would one go about answering questions such as this? Is a computational/brute-force approach the only viable option?

It is not possible, even without disallowing $2$-cycles.
I don't know if there is a "non-computational" approach. I translated the problem into an integer linear programming problem and used Maple.
